# Memory Usage Server DB Always Increase Even After Restart

Tags: sql-server, memory, ssis

i have problem with my server DB, memory usage is increase to 100% even after restart but sometime decrease. It makes some SQL Services cannot running any query and sometime SQL Services status are stuck on starting.

i have ssis/etl scheduler to get data from datawarehouse to database and ssis/etl for reporting

Windows Server 2012 R2

RAM Memory 64 GB

Services :

- SQL Server
- SQL Server Agent
- SQL Server Analysis Services
- SQL Server Browser
- SQL Server Integration Services 11.0
- SQL Server Reporting Services
- SQL Server VSS Writer

Top Ten Running Process :

- SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit
- Reporting Services Service
- McAfee Scanner service
- Windows Explorer
- termsvcs
- McAfee Threat Prevention Service
- WMI Provider Host
- Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services
- McAfee Adaptive Threat Protection Service
- Service Host: Local System

here are my questions :

1. what makes my server db memory usage is full?and how to trace?
2. is there any stuck query or locking query that causes use memory resource?and how to check it?

Comment: My understanding is that sql server will try and take as much memory as it can to help it manage caching etc, though in a manner which allows other processes to take it back as required. So that may not be an issue. Here is a good explanation: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/why-is-sql-server-consuming-more-server-memory

Answer (score 0):

You are running SSIS SQL and SSAS services in the same box which is highly un recommended.

You can limit how much memory each service uses by changing the following configurations.

SSAS:
LowMemoryLimit
TotalMemoryLimit
HardMemoryLimit

[Memory properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/server-properties/memory-properties?view=asallproducts-allversions)

SQL:
max server memory
[Server memory configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: thanks for answer, but i need an evidence what queries taking up more memory. Is there any queries to check?